# Get the value of a map field in cloud firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, maps

I have a code in getting the value of a map named Address.

```
Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("Address")) {
        Log.i(TAG, entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

And here is the output
**{Street=VP Inting Avenue, HouseNo=0186, Town=Tagbilaran City, Barangay=Poblacion I}**

But I want to get the values (*0186 VP Inting Avenue Poblacion I Tagbilaran City*) only and not including their keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
Log.i(TAG, document.get("Address.HouseNo") + document.get("Address.Street") +
           document.get("Address.Barangay") + document.get("Address.Town"));
```

If you know the exact path of the field, there is no need to loop over all fields. And with the `.` you can address nested fields.